# REST API streaming versus repeated GET requests

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a turn based game kind of like multiplayer checkers that works with firebase realtime database, so each client needs to know when moves are made.

I'm limited by third party framework that only allows REST API requests, but doesn't allow REST API streaming because there is no way to "Set the client's Accept header to text/event-stream" or "Respect HTTP Redirects, in particular HTTP status code 307".

So, I'm thinking of reading the database with GET requests every second to see if there is new data, but I'm worried that this could be inefficient in terms of data and cause a large bill. How much worse is this solution than a REST API streaming one and is it practical?

Answer (score 0):

Since in multiplayer games response time is very critical, I think you should think about how this may be inefficient in terms of user experience. But of course that will depend on how the game works.

But if you think it is ok users to have 1000ms delay, then the question is how much players will be playing the game daily, how long does each game take to finish (turn wise).

`((avg. turns per game) * (avg .# of players in a single game)) * (games played per day)` will be the minimum reads for only the game play part. Also you must consider if you will have to constantly check multiple documents.  Probably there will be many writes also reads on the other parts of the game.

So I think overall, it is very inefficient way to solve this problem in many ways.

What is the platform you are using? Maybe someone could find a way around somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase provides callback listeners for requests. You can attach `ChildEventListener` to your request to track real time changes in your database. As long as it is connected it will be considered a single request.

[Refer to this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener)

Comment: How do you add ChildEventListener to a HTTP REST API request?

Comment: Have a look at firebase realtime database sdk docs for your preferred language.